# Почему возникает ошибка MethodNotAllowedHttpException?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

При редактировании материала возникает ошибка:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

Файл Router:

```
Route::resource('/articles', 'Admin\ArticlesController', [
  'parameters' => [
    'articles' => 'alias'
  ]
]);
```

Код формы:

```
<div class="row">
  {!! Form::open(['url' => (isset($article->id)) ? route('admin.articles.update',['alias' => $article->alias]) : route('admin.articles.store'), 'method'=>'POST', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Заголовок статті:</b> <br>
        {!! Form::text('title', isset($article->title) ? $article->title  : old('title')) !!}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Псевдонім статті:</b> <br>
        {!! Form::text('alias', isset($article->alias) ? $article->alias  : old('alias')) !!}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Короткий опис:</b> <br>
        <div class="info-wrapper">
          {!! Form::textarea('desc', isset($article->desc) ? $article->desc : old('desc'), ['id'=>'desc', 'class' => 'materialize-textarea']) !!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Повний текст:</b> <br>
        <div class="info-wrapper">
          {!! Form::textarea('text', isset($article->text) ? $article->text : old('text'), ['id'=>'text', 'class' => 'materialize-textarea']) !!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @if(isset($article->img))
      <div class="col s12">
        <div class="info-block link-block">
          <b class="info-title">Теперішнє фото:</b> <br>
          <div class="info-wrapper">
            {{ Html::image(asset(env('THEME')).'/images/articles/'.$article->img, '', ['style'=>'width:500px']) }}
            {!! Form::hidden('old_image',$article->img) !!}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endif
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Фото статті:</b> <br>
        <div class="file-field input-field">
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Виберіть файл</span>
            {!! Form::file('img') !!}
          </div>
          <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Загружайте лише 1 картинку">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Категорія:</b> <br>
        <div class="input-field">
          {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, isset($article->category_id) ? $article->category_id  : '', ['placeholder' => 'Виберіть категорію статті']) !!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Ключові слова:</b> <br>
        <div class="input-field">
          {!! Form::text('keywords', isset($article->keywords) ? $article->keywords  : old('keywords')) !!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Мета опис:</b> <br>
        <div class="input-field">
          {!! Form::textarea('meta_desc', isset($article->meta_desc) ? $article->meta_desc : old('meta_desc'), ['id'=>'meta_desc', 'class' => 'materialize-textarea']) !!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="info-block link-block">
        <b class="info-title">Показувати на головній:</b>
        <p>
          <label>
            @if($article->show == 1)
              <input name="show" id="show" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="filled-in">
            @else
              <input name="show" id="show" type="checkbox" class="filled-in">
            @endif
            <span>Показувати статтю на головній сторінці</span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    @if(isset($article->id))
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">      
    @endif
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="info-block link-block flex-block">
        {!! Form::button('Зберегти', ['class' => 'btn btn-large', 'type'=>'submit']) !!}
      </div>
    </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
  <script>
    var options = {
      filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
      filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token={{ csrf_token() }}',
    };
    CKEDITOR.replace('desc', options);
    CKEDITOR.replace('text', options);
  </script>
</div>
```

При том, что добавление материала с этой самой формы работает нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [Ссылка](http://g.zeos.in/?q=MethodNotAllowedHttpException) на решение проблемы

Comment: Вот именно, что сначала я гуглил, но не найдя ответа я пришел сюда :)

Comment: Сам текст ошибки говорит Вам, что такой метод не разрешён. Вы забыли добавить поле `@method('PUT')`, к примеру. Ну или же  `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">`

Comment: Нет, у меня есть `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">`

Comment: @entithat Вот: 
`@if(isset($article->id))
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">      @endif`

Comment: а если нет $article->id то возникает токая проблема метода

Comment: @Aram77778, Да, возникает